# How can I get the text that is displayed for a trigger of a Windows scheduled task using .NET Framework?

Tags: .net, windows, powershell, scheduled-tasks

as I learned today, by `Get-ScheduledTask` command in the PowerShell I can retrieve much information about a scheduled task, also its triggers by the `Triggers` property that is printed out according to the following pattern:

```
Enabled            : True
EndBoundary        : 
ExecutionTimeLimit : 
Id                 : 
Repetition         : MSFT_TaskRepetitionPattern
StartBoundary      : 2016-03-06T03:00:00
DaysOfWeek         : 16
RandomDelay        : 
WeeksInterval      : 1
PSComputerName     :
```

But in interests of a user-friendly output message, I would like to receive the display text you can see when watching the trigger in the Windows taskplaner:

[image: Credits: http://winaero.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/Windows-10-the-list-of-triggers-600x344.png]
(Credits: http://winaero.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/Windows-10-the-list-of-triggers-600x344.png)

So how can I extract the "details" text like "At log on of any user" by .NET Framework (in PowerShell)? I have not been able to found such member of the `Get-ScheduledTask` return type.
(I have also taken a look at the [.NET `TaskScheduler` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler.getscheduledtasks#System_Threading_Tasks_TaskScheduler_GetScheduledTasks) which seems though unfortunately only treat single processes' internals.)

Do you know any way for this purpose? Or do I have to generate the display text manually?

Comment: `System.Threading.Tasks.TaskScheduler`, despite the name, has nothing at all to with Windows scheduled tasks; .NET `Task` instances represent fine-grained asynchronous operations while Windows scheduled tasks are far more high level. There are other managed wrappers for those, like [this one](http://taskscheduler.codeplex.com/), but I can't say if they would help you.

Answer (score 0):

I created a PowerShell function that handles this for our modules.

```
function Get-WindowsScheduledTaskTriggerDescription
{
    <#
    .SYNOPSIS
    Converts the triggers of a scheduled task into human readable text
    #>
    param ([Parameter(Mandatory=$true,ValueFromPipeline=$true)][Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.CimInstance]$task)
    begin {
        $dayNames = @("Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday")
    }
    process {
        if ($task.Triggers.Count -eq 0) {return}
        # Retrieve the first trigger (you can modify this if your task has multiple triggers)
        $triggers = $task.Triggers

        
        # Extract the friendly description
        foreach ($t in $triggers)
        {
            switch ($_.GetType().FullName) {
                "Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.CimInstance" {

                    # Initialize an empty description
                    
                    $description = ""
                    if ($t.Id) {
                        $description += "ID=$($t.ID) "
                    }
                    
                    $description += "Enabled=$($t.Enabled) "

                    # Check if the trigger repeats
                    if ($t.Repetition) {
                        if ($t.Repetition.Interval) {
                            $description += "Repeats every";
                            $TimeSpan =  [System.Xml.XmlConvert]::ToTimeSpan($t.Repetition.Interval)
                            foreach ($p in @("Days","Hours","Minutes","Seconds"))
                            {
                                if ($TimeSpan.$p -gt 0) {
                                    #Write-Host " $($repetitionTimeSpan.$p) $p"
                                    $description += " $($TimeSpan.$p) $p"
                                }
                            }
                        }
    
                        if ($t.Repetition.Duration) {
                            $description += " for a duration of";
                            $TimeSpan =  [System.Xml.XmlConvert]::ToTimeSpan($t.Repetition.Duration)
                            foreach ($p in @("Days","Hours","Minutes","Seconds"))
                            {
                                if ($TimeSpan.$p -gt 0) {
                                    #Write-Host " $($TimeSpan.$p) $p"
                                    $description += " $($TimeSpan.$p) $p"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        if ($repetitionInterval.TotalMinutes) {
                            $description += "Repeats every $($repetitionInterval.TotalMinutes) minutes"
                        }
                    }

                    # Check if the trigger has a specific days interval
                    if ($t.DaysInterval) {
    
                        $description += "Every $($t.DaysInterval) days"
                    }

                    # Check if the trigger specifies days of the week
                    if ($t.DaysOfWeek) {
                        $daysOfWeek = (1..7 | ForEach-Object {
                                            $dayIndex = ($_ + $t.DaysOfWeek - 1) % 7
                                            $dayNames[$dayIndex]
                                        } ) -join ','


                        $description += "Weekly on $daysOfWeek"
                    }

                    # Check if the trigger has a specific start time
                    if ($t.StartBoundary) {
                        $description += " at " + ([datetime]$t.StartBoundary).TimeOfDay.ToString()
                    }
                    
                    ## Output the final description
                    return $description
                }
                default {
                    # Fallback to displaying the trigger type
                    $_.GetType().Name
                }
            }
        }
        return $friendlyDescription
    }#process
}#function Get-WindowsScheduledTaskTriggerDescription
```

Example output:

- GoogleUpdateTaskMachineUA

  - Enabled=True Repeats every 1 Hours for a duration of 1 DaysEvery 1 days at 20:13:30
- MicrosoftEdgeUpdateTaskMachineCore:

  - Enabled=True Every 1 days at 06:12:00
- MicrosoftEdgeUpdateTaskMachineUA:

  - Enabled=True Repeats every 1 Hours for a duration of 1 DaysEvery 1 days at 05:42:00
- SCCM Client Policy Refresh:

  - Enabled=True Weekly on Saturday,Sunday,Monday,Tuesday,Wednesday,Thursday,Friday at 03:00:00
- SensorFramework-LogonTask-{d2bf6ee0-91cf-5437-e6a2-61286b7b7159}:

  - Enabled=True

Answer (score 0):

> How can I get the text that is displayed for a trigger of a Windows scheduled task using .NET Framework?

You can't, those strings are internal to the Task Scheduler widget itself.

> Do you know any way for this purpose? Or do I have to generate the display text manually?

No, and yes.

Answer (score -1):

The details of tasks are available as XML (the XLM property of the returned task object).

```
$taskinfo = [xml](Get-ScheduledTask <taskname>).xml 
$taskinfo.task.triggers
```

Should provide information about the task triggers.

Comment: I'm sorry, but this isn't helpful for me. First, `[xml](Get-ScheduledTask <taskname>).xml` returned an empty output for me whereas `(Get-ScheduledTask <taskname>)` didn't, second, the XML file of a scheduled task does not provide the textual representation of its trigger's details at all but only the technical information I am able to determinate via `$task.Triggers` (also see code block above) directly, too.
Have you got any other ideas? :)